# How to fit clothing rails into plasterboard to hold adequate weight?

Tags: drywall

I am converting hallway storage into a wardrobe.  The dimensions are

h 234cm
W 132cm
D 45cm

I would like to put up two rails for clothing and some shelving for loose items

My question is how would I fit the rails into plasterboard style walls so they can support the weight of potentially many clothes.

Are there certain fixtures or fittings I can buy? Is there anything  I should consider before I start?

Comment: 1.) [Find the studs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stud_finder). 2.) Attach the rail to the studs.

Comment: Most framing construction for drywall will have studs in the front and rear corners of the closet on both sides. Rails consisting of a piece of wood (1x4 or 1x6 types size in US measurements) can be cut that run from front inside edge of the closet to the rear corner. These can be fastened into the corner studs at the cloths rail height. Then attach the cloths rail hardware onto these rail boards. This will result in something way stronger than a kludged in hanger bolted or screwed right to drywall.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to mention I am in the uk would the stud solution still work?

Answer (score 8):

Find your studs (a studfinder can be useful, else you can drill test holes). Mark your studs. Once you find one they should be about 16" or 24" apart from center to center (this is the typical US measure, internationally YMMV).

Mount your clothes rails by drilling your mounting screws into the studs. (make sure your screws are long enough to penetrate your clothes rail, the plaster and into the studs)

From Evil Greebo: "If the studs are too near the front/back of the closet, you can mount a cross brace on the wall of the closet. Firmly connect it to the studs, then attach your closet rails to the cross brace."

Comment: If the studs are too near the front/back of the closet, you can mount a cross brace on the wall of the closet.  Firmly connect it to the studs, then attach your closet rails to the cross brace.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different kinds of bolts and screws you can use on hollow walls to be able to take weight.  Typically, you drill a hole first, then insert a special fitting into that hole, then attach your workpiece (shelf bracket, etc), then the bolt goes through the bracket and into the fitting.  An older style of these are toggle bolts, which require assembly before putting the fitting into the wall, which look like this:
[image: Toggle bolt]

but nowadays there are many different kinds, like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

or even these:

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend this kind of mounting for anything heavier than hanging wall art or a clock.

Comment: Agree with The Evil One and @waxeagle above.  See [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/what-benefit-do-plasterboard-drywall-screws-have/16787#16787)