# 4' double fluorescent lights fixture

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture

I want to mount 4 feet double fluorescent light fixture in my room celling. The celling is made of drywall, my question : is it safe to use drywall anchor in celling which is rated for 75 lbs to mount fixture or whatelse should i use to reinforce to support fixture on drywall celling? Drywall thickness is 3/4 inches.

Comment: There are probably joists supporting that drywall. Use a stud-finder to locate them, and you'll be able to drive real screws into real wood.

Comment: Anything listed [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/what-benefit-do-plasterboard-drywall-screws-have/16787#16787), except those marked 'light duty'.

Answer (score 1):

Drywall anchors are used in vertical walls and the rating is based on a combination of shear load (downward on the screw and anchor) and some tension load outward (based on an assumption of a load close to the wall).

Ceiling mounts are pure tension loads downward and the weak spot is the drywall, not the anchor. A thin diameter of crumbly plaster around the anchor is all that holds them in. Even flared, they form a narrow cone that is easily compromised.

For ceiling mounting, try very hard to find framing members. If that is not possible, use anchors that have significant perpendicular members, such as molly bolts or toggles. I favor [strap toggles](http://www.homedepot.com/p/The-Hillman-Group-1-4-in-x-2-1-2-in-Toggle-Straps-with-Screws-6-Pack-376260/202982713) like these

[image: strap toggle]

But I really urge screwing into framing if at all possible.

```
 Images and links are examples only, not endorsements of products or sources.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most drywall anchors are meant to be used vertically not horizontally. Walls yes ceilings NO. If you bought the anchors look at the box it should tell you. As for me I use toggle bolts and washers. Find the weight of the fixture and get the toggle bolt and washer to match.