# Are 4 toggle bolts enough to hold up a 32in TV?

Tags: drywall-anchor, television

My studs are 16 inches apart, but the stud is exactly centered on where I want my TV on the wall. The horizontal bars for my wall mount are 25 inches long (not long enough to reach the next studs to the left and right). So I am thinking I would need to use toggle bolts. Will toggle bolts be enough to hold the TV on the wall?

My TV is a [Sony Bravia KDL32BX420](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HYG9T6)
Weight: 20lbs

Mount: [Cheetah Mounts APTMM2B](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012S4APK)

Comment: What type of mount are you using? Two lag bolts in the center stud, might be better than toggle bolts.

Comment: @Tester101 I added the mount to my post. I ended up moving the mount over about an inch and then was able to put two bolts into the stud, and am then going to put 4 toggle bolts (1 in each corner)

Comment: At 20 lbs f or the TV (maybe 5-10 more for the mount), the lag bolts into the studs are really holding it up. The toggles are just keeping it from twisting. I would use strap toggles since they can be removed and reused.

Comment: @bib Can you give me a link to strap toggles? I found some but am not sure how you'd be able to remove them to reuse. The mount did come with 2 toggle bolts which are similar to those that I just found. I have to go to the hardware store to get two more.

Comment: In [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/what-benefit-do-plasterboard-drywall-screws-have/16787#16787) the strap toggles are the middle version. When I said *reuse*, I meant that the bolts can be taken out and reinserted. The toggle part itself remains in place.

Answer (score 4):

Use toggles, but also put at least one good fastener into the stud. (Even if you have to drill a new hole/holes in the mount.)