# What tool(s) should I use to make a hole in a wall and then put a screw in?

Tags: drywall, walls, screws, drill, screwdriver

I am doing some work in the kitchen and have purchased a metal bar to which I'm planning to hang some utensils. To mount the metal bar, I am required to make some holes on my kitchen wall and put some screws in them to hold the bar.

This is my kitchen wall:

[image: kitchen wall]

This is part of the mounting instructions of the bar:

[image: mounting instructions metal bar]

From research I have come across the terms percussion drill, impact driver, screwdriver, but I am confused as to which ones I should buy for what I need.

Keeping in mind that I am beginner (just got my first apartment!), what would be the minimum equipment necessary for me to be able to drill holes into walls and to drive screws into them ?.

Comment: The right tool depends on the material, do you know what your walls are made of? Some apartments are made of concrete block while others have plaster/lathe and others drywall.

Comment: Ikea also sells a cheap cordless drill that comes with a variety of anchors for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like StrongBad mentioned, it depends on what your walls are made of. If you're in the US, they're most likely drywall on top of wood studs, in which case you either drive screws directly into the studs, or use [anchors](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/what-benefit-do-plasterboard-drywall-screws-have/16787#16787) to secure the screws in the drywall itself. Studs are the best option, but they rarely line up with where you'd want them to be. For a kitchen utensil rack, anchors should be fine.

Tools: depending on the anchor type you choose, you'll probably need a drill (as an apartment-owner, a 12 or 18V cordless drill/driver combo will be invaluable) with a drill bit to drill the hole that the anchor goes into, and a Phillips-head screwdriver (or screwdriver bits for your drill) to drive the screw into the anchor.

Comment: And just to hit on the other tools you mentioned, you likely won't need an impact driver in an apartment (they generate a large amount of torque to drive screws quickly through tough wood). You might want a hammer drill if your walls are concrete, though I'd check with your landlord before drilling in that case.

Comment: Thanks, my walls are in France, I haven't done any house work before, so I will ask my landlord and get informed.

Comment: Why a 12 or 16 V cordless drill and not the more common 18 or 20 V?

Comment: @mmathis whoops, I meant 12 or 18. I have a 12V Bosch set that got me through years of apartment living handily -- the smaller size makes it easy to get into tight spots and it's powerful enough for all the hanging and drilling I did.