# Drywall anchors or wood studs when securing a TV?

Tags: drywall-anchor

Which is better to use for securing a TV to the wall?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/what-benefit-do-plasterboard-drywall-screws-have/16787#16787) covers your question. Short answer, STUDS.

Comment: We like question to show that the asker has done some research.  What drywall anchors are you considering?  What type of mount?  How big is the TV?  As asked, the question is too broad for us to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hit the studs, do not trust drywall anchors to hold up a TV.

Comment: Agreed.  However you think they would make a universal TV mount with some sort of  slide extender  for the holes to line up with studs in all homes with drywall.

Comment: They do, unless your studs are really far apart.

Comment: @VictorDean Many (most? all?) TV mounts have several sets of elongated holes which allows most installations to hit at least 1 stud with 2 bolts. Depending on the size of the mount and the stud spacing, many can get all 4 bolts into studs.