# Why can't I get this plastic drywall anchor into the hole?

Tags: drywall-anchor

I bought drywall anchors to hang a curtain rod, and followed the directions on the package (use 1/4" drill bit to make the hole for the anchor, then push it in). When I push, it won't go. If I try to lightly tap it with a hammer, the plastic anchor just deforms and it doesn't go any further. I don't want to make the hole bigger than what they specified on the package - what could I be doing wrong?

Or maybe these plastic anchors are just junk?

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Triple-Grip-8-x-1-1-4-in-Anchors-with-White-Screws-5-Pack-178S/202531180

Comment: What's behind the drywall? Not enough space perhaps?

Comment: How deep did the drill bit go?

Comment: It's clear that there is something behind the drywall. That's why the anchor is deforming. The anchors were designed for drywall installed over an empty cavity.  You probably drilled into a wooden or metal support beam.  This could be a good  thing because you can use a regular wood screw instead of the anchors.

Comment: The drill bit went plenty of the way in - the anchor definitely isn't hitting something behind the wall. It gets caught up on those little expanding "shoulders" that are coming off its sides.

Answer (score 4):

I actually really like those linked triple grip wall anchors (linked by OP). The package often comes with its own drywall drill bit as well. The trick to using them is to pinch the "shoulders" in until they are flush with the sides of the anchor body before pushing them into the hole. Drywall is fairly chalky and brittle, so it will give a little bit where needed to let the shoulders through. Once in, these are nice, strong, low-profile anchors. The auger ones are a lot more destructive and tear up a lot of drywall if they fail. But I've used those successfully in the past as well.

Answer (score 2):

The are a couple of reasons why it might not go in, if it doesn't go in at all, then the hole is too small -try wiggling the drill on the way out to open it up.
When you were drilling the pilot hole did you hit a stud?  You should only encounter resistance when you are drilling for the first 1/2" and then nothing after that.  If that's the case, then move over and try in a better spot or just screw into the stud itself. (Provided you didn't drill too far into the stud).

Frankly, I don't like that kind of anchor anymore.  I prefer the ones that look like an auger.  They work really well.

[image]

[What are the advantages of different types of drywall anchors?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-are-the-different-types-of-drywall-anchors-and-what-are-the-advantages-of)

Comment: I wiggled the drill bit a little bit, but I was concerned about making the hole too big (since I used the exact drill bit they recommended) and having the anchor not have enough to grip on to. Looks like it makes sense to give up on those and get the anchors you're recommending.

Comment: @Charles I second Muppet1856's answer.  I have used the anchors you have now and I've had nothing but headaches from them.  The auger anchors on the other hand have always worked for me.