# Expanding nylon dowel to fix a U shaped rail fails

Tags: shelving

I'm trying to fix a rail and bracket type of shelf [this one to be precise](http://www.leroymerlin.fr/v3/p/produits/cremaillere-simple-blanche-en-acier-entraxe-50mm-h200cm-e10968).

Having a plasterboard wall, I picked self expanding nylon dowels [like this](http://www.leroymerlin.fr/v3/p/produits/50-chevilles-vis-a-expansion-ou-a-verrouillage-de-forme-standers-6x35mm-e1400138066).

My problem is, the rail being U shaped, as soon as I screw, the dowel is pulled out from the wall instead of expanding into it, as expected o_O How should I proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The best drywall anchors](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/what-benefit-do-plasterboard-drywall-screws-have/16787#16787) are **toggle bolts**. Those plastic things are for hanging pictures (if that; throw them away). Use the [metal kind](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-are-the-different-types-of-drywall-anchors-and-what-are-the-advantages-of) if you must.

Comment: thx, I used metal ones, and hopefully, the shelf is standing still :)"read head" market them as `vix`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you slip a small screwdriver through the slot to hold the expansion piece into place until the screw expands it enough to stay in place on its own?

Otherwise, maybe you can find a small metal spacer to slide on the screw behind the bracket to help hold the expansion piece while you tighten the screw:

[image]

(image from [TwistedThrottle.com](http://www.twistedthrottle.com/barkbusters-20mm-spacer-and-bolt-for-providing-extra-clearance-around-master-cylinder))

A stack of small washers might also work.